# Compile quietly unless there are errors

Tags: window, compilation

I want to run `compile` or `recompile`, but I don't want to see the `*compilation*` buffer pop up unless there's an error, or not at all. If the compilation succeeds, I should just see a notification in the echo area. This is how AUCTeX works; I want it for arbitrary compilation commands in arbitrary modes.

This is a small wheel to be sure, but I can't find it built in (as of Emacs 24.3). Before I go on about reinventing it, does this already exist somewhere?

Comment: I don't know if there is such a thing. But if I wanted to do something like that, I'd start with `compilation-start-hook` and `compilation-filter-hook`. First to bury the buffer (and possibly rename it), second to watch for errors and then bring it back up.

Comment: Have a look at `(setq outwin (display-buffer outbuf '(nil (allow-no-window . t))))`, line 1693 of `compile.el` in the master branch -- the function `compilation-start`.  If you are an anti-source modifier who relishes advice and so forth (i.e., among the majority of Emacs users), you can set up a `display-buffer-alist` rule to suit your needs.  A couple of years ago I took `compile.el` and made it my own custom setup -- so I just modify it directly at will.